# python match variable groups

Tags: python

My target is reformat below code from A function to B function,which means using Log.d code statement to replace the StringBuilder statements.

```
public void A() {
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("i Counter:");
    sb.append(i);
    Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
    int j = 0;
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    sb1.append("i Counter:");
    sb1.append(i);
    sb1.append(" j Counter:");
    sb1.append(j);
    Log.d(TAG, sb1.toString());
}

public void B() {
    int i = 0;
    Log.d(TAG, "i Counter" + i);
    int j = 0;
    Log.d(TAG, "i Counter" + i + " j Counter" + j);
}
```

I am thinking about using regex to match the content in append() call. 
But the append lines is not known, it maybe in range 1 to N.

Is python regex a good tool to solve this problem?

What's the best language if not?

Comment: If I understand this correct, you are asking for some Python code to transform the above Java method (using `StringBuilder` to the below form (using `+`), is this correct?

Comment: right! I wish to reformat the code from StringBuilder to Log.d.

Comment: What do you mean from "StringBuilder to Log.d". Are you trying to write Java or Python?

Comment: @lguananaut Actually wish to reformat Java code by python script! code java by python :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with a replacement function that joins all the strings within the `append` calls with `+`:

```
import re
def build(m):
    return ''.join((m.group(3), ' + '.join(re.findall(r'%s\.append\((.*)\);' % m.group(1), re.sub(r'^(?!\s+%s\.append\b).*' % m.group(1), '', m.group(2), flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))), ');'))
print(re.sub(r'StringBuilder (\w+) = new StringBuilder\(\);(.*?)(Log.d\(\w+, )\1\.toString\(\)\);', build, s, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

so that given:

```
s = '''public void A() {
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("i Counter:");
    sb.append(i);
    Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
    int j = 0;
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    sb1.append("i Counter:");
    sb1.append(i);
    sb1.append(" j Counter:");
    sb1.append(j);
    // no matching below
    sb1.append(x);
    Log.d(TAG, sb1.toString());
}'''
```

this outputs:

```
public void A() {
    int i = 0;
    Log.d(TAG, "i Counter:" + i);
    int j = 0;
    Log.d(TAG, "i Counter:" + i + " j Counter:" + j);
}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I want. One more question: how to enhance it to match append in continues lines only? If any other line not append inserted between Log.d and append lines, do not match it.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've updated my answer with the new requirement then.